# R project WD changes "on its own"

Tags: r, github

I'm working on a project involving several people. We are using GitHub and a Rproject to be able to work on this project on different computers.
But I'm facing a really weird issue when I try to load files and/or get my working directory:

- When I type `getwd()` in R console, I indeed get the path where the project is saved on my computer
  `> getwd()`
  `[1] "/media/Data/Documents/my_R_project"`
- When I save `getwd()` in an object, the WD is not the same and now moves to the path were the script are saved:
  `folderpath <- getwd()`
  `> folderpath`
  `[1] "/media/Data/Documents/my_R_project/R/Script"`

I get the same issue when I try to load a file which is located in `/media/Data/Documents/my_R_project/R/Data`: when I use `read_csv` (or any other function like it) and write the file path as
`read_csv("R/Data/file.csv")` I get and error stating me that there is no such file in the directory `/media/Data/Documents/my_R_project/R/Script/R/Data/`.
How could I resolve this and make the WD used in `read_csv()` be the right one (`"/media/Data/Documents/my_R_project"`) so that I don't have to specify the full path every time and that people on another computer can run my script?
I'm working on Ubuntu LTS 20.04

Answer (score 0):

In the end, the error was due to a conflict between the WD of the project and the WD used when I knitted the .Rmd file. The problem was solved by changing the knit options and set its directory as the project directory.